# Access database two primary keys

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have two primary keys in one table that should be in a relationship with another table. 
So I should have two foreign keys in that table but I can´t get it working.
Because it´s says "No unique index found for the referenced field of the primary table."
When I try to connect them.

Comment: A table can't have more than one primary key. You can have a primary key made up of multiple fields (these are called composite primary keys).

Comment: Ok, that is what I mean I have been doing. So I have one primary key that is made up by multiple of fields.

Comment: This means that the combination of fields must be unique i.e. you could have values like `A,B`, `A,A` but not another `A,A`. This means that any foreign key relationship that this is the "parent" of requires *both* fields to be a part of the relationship.

Comment: *@Lime3003*, just a side note.  It is better not to use *composite primary keys*.  Why not just use a field of type *Long Integer* and set that as the primary key.  Ideally primary keys should not contain any significant values.  They should be used just for relating to other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change one of the columns to not be a "key" rather make it "unique" ("unique" is mentioned in the error message you are getting.